# Symfony 2 Error in getting logged user

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to get current logged user in my extended bundle

```
$user = $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser();
```

&

```
$user   = $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser();
```

returns same result something like `string(5) "anon."`

```
$user = $this->getUser(); return `NULL`
```

Below is the code I tried

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class ClientController extends Controller
{

  public function clientDashboardAction()
  {
    $user   = $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser();
    echo '<pre>';
    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user);
    echo '</pre>';
    // returns string(5) "anon."

    $user = $this->getUser();
    echo '<pre>';
    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user);
    echo '</pre>';
   //returns NULL

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Client:clientDashboard.html.twig');
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my code , Pls help me Guyz ........

Comment: As you know, the token will return 'anon' if you aren't logged into the system. Could you post your user class and also your configuration?

Comment: In addition, you can prevent users to reach that page giving a minimum role to the page in the security.yml file.

Comment: `getUser()` in the controller checks whether the "user" returned from the token is an object. If not (eg ".anon") it returns null instead. See https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php#L314-L339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution I use multiple firewalls ( admin side & front users side ) in security and system will not share context between different firewalls

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        admin:
            # ...
            context: my_context
        main:
            # ...
            context: my_context
```

The above code solved my Issues, 
Thanks for the support ....